# How to show cell shadows that spills over to another cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the following card style in my app, and I'm having an issue with the shadow element for each card.

[image: Invision UI Kit]

## Issue

The shadow of a cell is not displayed behind the cell directly below it.

UITableView is used, and cell background is set to transparent.

[image]

## Question #

- Is it possible to allow the shadow to **'spill over'** to the cell area below it?

I suspect the shadow cut-off is caused by the cell's height. I don't want to increase the space between each 'card', so increasing the cell's height is not a good option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you might possibly be able to solve it by setting each cell's clipsToBounds to false and/or their layer's masksToBounds to false.  I doubt it'll work, but is worth a try.

What I suspect you'll need to do is specify the cells as transparent, then place a view within them that is not as high as the cell, to leave room for that view's shadow.  So the view looks like a card with shadow, and is offset within the transparent cell so that the card + shadow fits perfectly within the cell.

Comment: I have already specified the cell as transparent and had the view within it that is not as high as the cell. The problem is that I didn't want to leave too much room for the shadow within the cell, and I wanted the shadow to just "overflow" to the next cell. Anyway, I tried your suggestion and set the cell's maskToBounds to false and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This looks obvious in retrospective. For me the problem was in `UICollectionViewCell.contentView.maskToBounds` because that one cannot be set in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the cell's backgroundColor to clearColor.